# Elasticsearch search for exact string instead of partial

Tags: elasticsearch

I have issue writing the correct query for elasticsearch when it comes to finding exact string.

Say I have a user's full name that is "John Adam" and another is "John Adam Clark"

When I search for "John Adam", it returns both names when I only want to have "John Adam"

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "query_string": {
                "default_field": "my_data.user.name.full",
                "query": "John Adam"
            }
         },

    }
}
```

I tried adding `\"` before and after the name as well, no change. Is it possible to limit search to exact string?

EDIT: This field is analyzed. I do have another field with the same info that's not analyzed. However due to other operation, if I can perform this task with analyzed field, that'd be great

Comment: Your `my_data.user.name.full` field must be `not_analyzed`, is it the case?

Comment: @Val actually it has costumed analyzer. I do copy it to another one field that's not analyzed. I don't know if there's anyway to do it with the analyzed one. I know tokenizing is an issue when it comes to this. I just don't know if there's anyway to overcome this.

Comment: Please share your current mapping, then.